# How to init ionic app after git clone?

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework, bower

I want to run the ionic app that I cloned from git. I can see that there are `package.json` and also `bower.json` files. Is there a way I could (using npm or bower) install plugins and platforms that are specified in `package.json` file?
Here is the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "example: App providing example, isn't that obvious?",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "com-badrit-base64",
    "cordova-plugin-camera",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs",
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ]
}
```

Thanx!

EDIT:
I found out that `ionic state restore` does all the job for me!

Comment: just type 'npm install' in root directory of the project..!it will install everything from package.json

Comment: i ran into some errors with npm install, but that was an issue that gulp is not installed or something like that. I meanwhile found out that it's enough to do `ionic state restore` <-- this will restore things like plugins and platforms from `package.json`